# Performant hooking of OpenGL to draw an overlay - problems with multiple contexts

Tags: opengl, graphics, hook

Like others in previous questions, I'm trying to hook an arbitrary OpenGL application to draw an overlay onto it. I've hooked SwapBuffers and created a separate context on first call to draw into. See [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348450/render-inside-of-opengl-scene-from-an-external-application-using-an-injected-dll) for the general idea.

There are two big problems I'm hitting. First, the calls to wglMakeCurrent to set/restore the context before/after drawing absolutely destroy performance. Is this expected? I need to look more into using _ARB_context_flush_control as mentioned by @datenwolf in a comment on [this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406076/dll-injection-drawing-simple-game-overlay-with-opengl).

Second, the overlay only works well on one of my two machines. On my machine with an AMD graphics card, the overlay flickers in that it is only present in some of the frames. The technique being used is the same as that used in the [Mumble VOIP client server project](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble), and that project exhibits the same overlay flicker problem. Any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: I read your first paragraph and as someone who makes a living doing this sort of thing, I'm left asking WHY? Are you trying to avoid disrupting the state machine? Your overlay should be drawn from the same context immediately before the buffer swap (to avoid any kind of command sync issues between two separate contexts). The only thing you might consider is doing processing logic immediately following a buffer swap and display immediately before (you'll have an extra frame of latency, but you're less likely to hurt the performance of the application you're hooking).

Comment: Also, if we're discussing Windows, it may help to hook wglSwapBuffers instead. SwapBuffers is dispatched through `wglSwapBuffers` on ICDs, some developers call `wglSwapBuffers` directly even though they are not supposed to.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said wglSwapBuffers. Yes, I was using the second context to try to avoid disturbing the state machine, based on the answers in the first question I linked to. In those questions, without a second context, folks have trouble getting the state right so that their overlay shows up, and the answers/recommendation are to use that second context. I'll look into trying to get the current context's state in a place where I can draw and trying to reset it back.

Comment: Also, I looked a bit at how FRAPS does its overlay, using the apitrace tool (https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace). It does not use a second context, but I don't think it draws into the existing context either based on the opengl calls I see.

Comment: As long as you avoid the fixed-function pipeline, there's very little disruption to state that you have to worry about. You'll be using your own program object, ideally your own vertex array object, etc. Those objects encapsulate their internal state and most of the stuff you need to worry about is limited to buffer, program binding and viewport / framebuffer. Querying that stuff from the state machine is perfectly valid and not going to cause performance problems, you can also track state changes if you hook the appropriate functions (but run into problems with extensions and display lists).